# Externalized BuildConfig in Grails

Tags: grails, configuration, config, buildconfig

We can load different configuration files for `Config.groovy` by specifying a class that is a config script. [Externalized Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized):

```
grails.config.locations = [com.my.app.MyConfig]
```

Is it possible to do something similar for `BuildConfig.groovy`?

I want to place CodeNarc configuration in another config file. As it uses Groovy's [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) syntax, I try to merge config objects, but not works.

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(..)    
this.merge(config)
```

Any different trick?

Comment: Found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/910438) maybe helps you.

Comment: this sounds like a CodeNarc bug - you should be able to just define where you keep this configuration instead of polluting BuildConfig

Comment: @Sérgio: that's a wonderful gist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to so that.

The Codenarc plugin lets you keep your codenarc configuration externally. See here 
[http://grails.org/plugin/codenarc#Configuring The Codenarc Properties](http://grails.org/plugin/codenarc#Configuring%20The%20Codenarc%20Properties)

Included here is an example codenarc setup I have in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
codenarc.processTestUnit = false
codenarc.processTestIntegration = false
codenarc.processViews = true
codenarc.propertiesFile = 'grails-app/conf/codenarc.properties'
codenarc.ruleSetFiles = [
        "rulesets/basic.xml",
        "rulesets/braces.xml",
        "rulesets/grails.xml",
        "rulesets/groovyism.xml",
]
```

Here we also define an external `codenarc.properties` file which we use to turn parts of rules from each of the included rulesets on/off. Example of this `codenarc.properties` file contents is included here:

```
# some gsp's MUST have embedded CSS and/or embedded Javascript which requires the use of semicolons.
UnnecessarySemicolon.doNotApplyToFileNames = *.gsp
# we're not going to enforce these
UnnecessaryGString.enabled = false
UnnecessaryReturnKeyword.enabled = false
```

So you can steer away from polluting your BuildConfig with un-wanted things as Tomas mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Tom